# MYSQL Select colum A or B if either is = X and Join on the other non-X-value in Colum A or B

Tags: mysql

I have a table of pairwise distances of items. 
Given an Item ID I want to list the Paired ItemID's.
I then want to join this to another table that has more details on the other Items that match.

**Table A.**

```
    +-------+-----------+----------+
    | ItemA | ItemB     | Distance |
    +-------+-----------+----------+
    |    12 |     33    | 13.0     |
    |    12 |      4    | 14.6     |
    |    43 |     12    | 17.8     |
    |    44 |     12    | 19.6     |
    +-------+-----------+----------+
```

My best guess is to select a row that has X as a Value in either the ItemA or ItemB, and have an output column AS ITEM.

**Semi-complete/wrong Mysql:**

```
Select *, (NON X Column Value) AS ITEM FROM TableA WHERE (ItemA = X) OR (ItemB = X)
```

I can add the JOIN part to the query later.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`(NON X Column Value)` should be like `CASE WHEN ItemA = X THEN ItemB ELSE ItemA END`

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT ItemA as Start, ItemB as Destination
FROM   TableA
WHERE  ItemA = X
UNION
SELECT ItemB as Start, ItemA as Destination
WHERE  ItemB = X
```

Once you have the table above you can then join it with the other table to show more details.

Hope this helps